# How should I parse JSON which has its keys and values' accents escaped without affecting the escapings in the field values?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Querying the Stack Overflow websockets with `155-questions-active` I get the following (malformatted) JSON:

```
{
    "action":"155-questions-active",
    "data":
        "{
            \"siteBaseHostAddress\":\"stackoverflow.com\",
            \"id\":23747905,
            \"titleEncodedFancy\":\"Load sqlite extension in Django\",
            \"bodySummary\":\"I have built a sqlite <snip>\",
            \"tags\":[\"django\",\"sqlite\",\"pysqlite\"],
            \"lastActivityDate\":1400544795,
            \"url\":\"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747905/<snip>\",
            \"ownerUrl\":\"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1311165/pro-chats\",
            \"ownerDisplayName\":\"Pro Chats\",
            \"apiSiteParameter\":\"stackoverflow\"
        }"
}
```

After applying some fixes

```
    private string MakeJsonCapable(string input)
    {
        input = input.Trim();
        input = input.Replace("data\":\"", "data\":");
        input = input.Remove(input.LastIndexOf("\""), 1);
        input = input.Replace("\\", string.Empty);

        return input;
    }
```

I get to this result:

```
{
  "action": "155-questions-active",
  "data": {
    "siteBaseHostAddress": "stackoverflow.com",
    "id": 23747905,
    "titleEncodedFancy": "Load sqlite extension in Django",
    "bodySummary": "I have built a sqlite <snip>",
    "tags": [
      "django",
      "sqlite",
      "pysqlite"
    ],
    "lastActivityDate": 1400544795,
    "url": "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/23747905\/<snip>",
    "ownerUrl": "http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/users\/1311165\/pro-chats",
    "ownerDisplayName": "Pro Chats",
    "apiSiteParameter": "stackoverflow"
  }
}
```

Which is now acceptable JSON (I'm using [some online JSON format tool](http://jsonprettyprint.com/) to verify this) that gets parsed perfectly by JSON.NET.

The problem occurs when a value (so far I've only seen it in `bodySummary` but I suspect  `titleEncodedFancy` is also likely to have this) contains a `"`. The literal value that is being passed before making it Json-able is `\\\"Compliant Solution\\\"`: 3 backslashes and an accent.

Note that this is the *literal value* and does not include any backslashes from the debugger: this is taken directly from the textview; the watch variable shows 7 backslashes.

Obviously this is a problem because now my `bodySummary` contains an unescaped `"` which will corrupt the deserializing. For this reason I can't create a custom `JsonConverter` to escape them myself either since it won't get the right values in the first place.

How can I remove the unwanted backslashes that appear in front of the accents that signify the start and end of a field's name and its value?

Alternatively: maybe I am parsing the `data` field incorrectly in the first place. If so: what is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is data that has been serialized to a string, placed inside another object and then serialized a second time.  To get everything back out correctly, you can reverse the process.  Define two classes, one for the outer serialization and one for the inner:

```
class Outer
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

class Inner
{
    public string SiteBaseHostAddress { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleEncodedFancy { get; set; }
    public string BodySummary { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public int LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string OwnerUrl { get; set; }
    public string OwnerDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string ApiSiteParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
Outer outer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Outer>(json);
Inner inner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Inner>(outer.Data);
```

When you do this, do NOT apply the "fixes" to the input string.  Let the JSON parser do its job.

**EDIT**

If you want to keep the parent-child relationship, you'll need a custom `JsonConverter` to handle the deserialization of the child object.  To do this, you first need to change the definition of the outer class to this:

```
class Outer
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(InnerConverter))]
    public Inner Data { get; set; }
}
```

Create the `InnerConverter` class like this:

```
class InnerConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Inner));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Inner>(token.ToString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And finally, you can deserialize like this:

```
Outer outer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Outer>(json);
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of doing it this way instead of keeping the parent-child structure?

Comment: Only that it works with a minimum of fuss.  It's possible to keep the parent-child structure, but you'll need a little more code to do it.  If you don't mind the child having a different property name than `Data`, you can simply add an additional property to the parent object to hold the deserialized child instance, and then add the child to the parent after the deserialization.  If you need the child property to be called `Data` and actually hold the instance rather than a string, then you will likely need a converter to be able to deserialize the parent.

Comment: Yeah, I wound up going with a simple converter which also maintains the child-parent structure with the actual instance. I'll add it for completeness sake.

Comment: I just added the converter approach to my answer; didn't see your comment until just now.

Comment: I noticed I was using `CanConvert` inappropriately so it's still helpful. I'm reading my token with `reader.Value as string;` while you use `JToken.Load(reader).ToString()`; is there a difference between the two?

Comment: For simple string values, not really.  I'm in the habit of using `JToken.Load(reader)` in my converters because in many cases (complex objects) it is far easier to use the API of `JToken` than to use the reader directly.  But using the reader is a little more efficient.

Comment: Alright, thanks for elaborating! This was very helpful insight.

Answer (score 1):

Following Brian Rogers' suggestion I created a simple converter which handles it all for me:

### Response

```
public sealed class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("action")]
    public string Action { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof (DataConverter))]
    public Data Data { get; internal set; }
}
```

### Data

```
public sealed class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("siteBaseHostAddress")]
    public string SiteBaseHostAddress { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("titleEncodedFancy")]
    public string TitleEncodedFancy { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("bodySummary")]
    public string BodySummary { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("tags")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastActivityDate")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof (EpochTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("url")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof (UriConverter))]
    public Uri QuestionUrl { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("ownerUrl")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof (UriConverter))]
    public Uri OwnerUrl { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("ownerDisplayName")]
    public string OwnerDisplayName { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty("apiSiteParameter")]
    public string ApiSiteParameter { get; internal set; }
}
```

### DataConverter

```
internal sealed class DataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var value = reader.Value as string;
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now I can deserialize it entirely with

```
var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);
```